# sub process returns error code(1) while installing tomcat7

Tags: python, ubuntu, tomcat7

I am trying to install tomcat 7 on my Ubuntu machine.

This is the error I am getting.

Can someone help me out in this..

> Job for tomcat7.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status tomcat7.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
>   invoke-rc.d: initscript tomcat7, action "start" failed.
>   dpkg: error processing package tomcat7 (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    tomcat7
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I get the same error when I am trying to run upgrade/update commands too.

Comment: Check this - http://askubuntu.com/questions/724180/error-while-install-tomcat7

Comment: Also  I think this error has nothing to do with python.

Comment: that didn't help me @DineshPundkar ...